# Using JQuery to Resize a Div to Match Window Dimensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Here is the code that DOES NOT work:

(The behavior is that the div doesn't change size. Note that I am also using JScrollPane on this div. [I mean the javascript library and **not** the Swing component]).

```
function resizeDivs()
{
    alert( "BEFORE\n#page width, height: " + $('#page').css( "width" ) + "," + $('#page').css( "height" ) );
    alert( "window width, height: " + $(window).width() + "," + $(window).height() );

    $('#page').css( "width", $(window).width() );
    $('#page').css( "height", $(window).height() );

    alert( "AFTER\n#page width, height: " + $('#page').css( "width" ) + "," + $('#page').css( "height" ) ); 
}
```

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/9XvcA/ - probably something to do with jScrollPane.

Comment: Works like a charm for me: http://jsfiddle.net/TVHbY/. Edit: ah, you beat me to it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see why your code shouldn't work. You can see the very same thing work fine right here on Stack Overflow:

```
$("#question-header").css("width", $(window).width());
```

I suspect that your code is getting called before the resize event has fully completed in the browser. Perhaps you could work around this using a timer, putting this wherever your resize callback is:

```
setTimeout('resizeDivs()', 10);
```

I'd also check for other CSS/layout issues that could be interfering.

Comment: Personally, I would not use 0 ms as there is a formal minimum delay of 4 ms (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout#Minimum_delay_and_timeout_nesting).

Comment: Found it. It was the other css issues that were confusing the matter. Your comment helped me to focus on this. Thank you!

Comment: I didn't know that, pimvdb. Thanks for the tip!